# Error while executing ExecuteNonQuery() function in c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2007

I'm executing an Insert statement from c# with values extracted from TextBox Controls in my gui.

I've only 2 columns with not null constrain in my DB

for eg : my insert statement is all are `VARCHAR` fields including ssn and dbate is date type

```
insert into emp (fname,minit,lname,dbate,ssn,sex) values ('arun','','','','12345','')
```

This works fine if all values are entered but when I enter null values, I get Data MisMatch error like a statement above while executing the statement .while executing sql directly in sql2005 the query works fine .

```
string myInsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Employee (fname,minit,lname,ssn,bdate,address,sex) values  ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "')";


 OleDbCommand myCommand2 = new OleDbCommand(myInsertQuery, mycon)


myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Do you have an example of your c# code ?

Comment: Which fields are in the table have not null constrain?

Comment: can u paster your code . so that we can look on it. its problem of having null constraint. share your C# code.

Comment: posted  the code .while debugging ,I took the string in myInsertquery and ran it against salserver it worked fine but the back end i m using here is ms access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might wanna try:

```
insert into emp (fname,minit,lname,dbate,ssn,sex) values ('arun', NULL, NULL, NULL,'12345', NULL)
```

**Check if the user is typing some characters like ' and -- it can easily corrupt your syntax!!!**

OFF-TOPIC BUT RELATED: By getting your values directly from the textbox youre allowing anyone to inject SQL on your application, its therefore a flaw. You can avoid it by parametrizing your query, such as follow:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * where Pk = @param1");
cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Int);
cmd.Parameters["@param1"].Value = txtPk.text;
```

Comment: Using the above parameterized example you can say `cmd.Parameters["@param1"].Value = txtPk.Text==string.Empty?DBNull.Value:(object)txtPk.Text;` to mark values which are null. Do make sure to Debug and put a watch on the final sql generated by your query.

Answer (score 0):

If `dbdate` is `date` type, as you say it is, it's normal that you get a `type mismatch error` if the value in `textbox5` does not contain text in an appropriate format. e.g. '10-12-2011'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider somewhere to make a verification of your textbox to make sure they contains an appropriate value.
(If they are empty, be sure to put a string.empty value or any default value required by your application).

Difficult to tell otherwise because your code is a litle bit incomplete to give a more precise answer.

Comment: i dont get error if i enter all values but only get error if i dont enter values for some fields like bdate ,sex

Comment: For the fields that can contains null value, the application gives you the same result when you specify a string.empty value or a DBNull.Value ?